# Fama Macbeth and Momentum factor

Tags: factor-models, asset-pricing, auto-correlation, factor-investing, paneldata

I am working on a Fama MacBeth regression with excess returns on the LHS and Size, Value an Momentum factors on the RHS. In literature, the Momentum factor is often definded as the cumulative past 6 month returns of a certain equity.

The Fama Macbeth procedure accounts for cross-sectional correlation of the residuals but it is not suitable to account for serial correlation. Cochrane (2009) argues that this is not a Problem for asset pricing models, because stock returns are likely to be uncorrelated over time.

How is it possible that many papers use Fama Macbeth regressions to estimate a Momentum factor which is actually based on serial correlation? It seems like a contradiction to me. Do I miss something?